# How to copy data from a table to another with HBase Coprocessor

Tags: java, hbase

We are building tools above HBase. We have a very big table in HBase and we want to copy some rows from it with a start row key and end row key to a new table. My previous thought is write a coprocessor for that. Then, I noticed we now have a new API named CopyTable, I think I can use that one for this function. Is any suggestions for other method for coping table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Export and Import option or snapshot. Can you let us know why you need coprocessor. They are intended for different purpose of event based for various operations

Comment: Thanks! We are building tools above HBase. We have a very big table in HBase and we want to copy some rows from it with a start row key and end row key to a new table. My previous thought is write a coprocessor for that. Then, I noticed we now have a new API named CopyTable, I think I can use that one for this function.

Comment: Yes, copyTable has option to copy based on date, row key range, versions and column families. So it fits into your requirements.